# Searching in a tree

Tags: algorithm

Given a tree with N vertices numbered from 1 to N. The vertex 1 is the root of the tree. Each vertex is assigned with an integer weight. A remove operation can remove sub-tree rooted at an arbitrary vertex u. We must use remove operations so that the total weight(sum of the value) of the remaining vertices is largest. For Example:

```
                     1
                   /   \
                  1     -1  (Remove)
                 /       \
  (Remove)    -1         -1
```

So 2 Remove operation is allowed such that weight is greater than the previous .

How to proceed this type of problem which algorithms are used , since a node in a tree can have more than 2 branches.

My Approach: First i found the weight at each node i.e

```
                -1
               /   \
              0     -2  
             /       \
           -1         -1
```

Code:

```
static int search(int a,ArrayList<Integer>[] som){
            int sum=0;          
            check[a]=true;
            for(int j=0;j<som[a].size();j++){
                weight[a] = value[a];
            if(!check[som[a].get(j)])
            {

             weight[a]+= search(som[a].get(j),som);
            }
        }
        return weight[a];


 }
```

I don't know how to approach after this , can dynamic programming would be useful, please provide some algorithms or any approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some kind of dynamics here

let's say

```
d[i] - maximum sum for subtree starting from vertex i
```

so

```
d[i] = max(0, a[i] + those children of vertex i whose d[] > 0)
```

that will be calculated while leaving vertex during dfs (same as weight)

so for your example tree d will look like

```
            2(5)
           /   \
          1(2)    0(4)  
         /       \
       0(1)         0(3)
```

bracket numbers are order